# Position points within an oval-like area

Tags: graphing-functions, random

I am developing a website and I'm trying to load multiple "points" within a `<div>`.
 If you don't know much about web development, a `div` is just a rectangle. See the picture below, where the purple box represents the dimensions of the `div`, which is **exactly** 150x700 pixels.

[image]

Note that in browsers, the y-axis is flipped. As you can see, my `div` is not actually rectangular in appearance, though it is still manipulated as though it were. It has rounded corners, each corner's `border-radius` being 75px.

When I load my website, several dots (like the one in the picture) are appended to the **inside** of the `div`. Each dot has a *specific* y-value, and the x value is randomized between 1 and 150.

**The problem** is that if a dot has something near the top or bottom- for example, `y=690`-
 the x value can still be randomized in a way that the dot will appear outside of the rounded corners.

**What I need** help with is determining a way to still have a *randomized* x-value, but is also restricted to stay within the borders of the `div`, rather than it's rectangular frame.

I'm sorry if this is too short an explanation: I currently have to leave my computer. I will try to edit in more information and reply to comments as soon as I can. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $1\leq y\leq 75$ take random $x$ between $[ 76-\sqrt{75^2-(y-75)^2}]$ and $[74+\sqrt{75^2-(y-75)^2}]$, where $[\cdot ]$ indicates integer part.

For $76\leq y\leq 625$ take random $x$ between $1$ and $150$.

Finally, for $626\leq y\leq 700$ take random $x$ between $[ 76-\sqrt{75^2-(y-626)^2}]$ and $[74+\sqrt{75^2-(y-626)^2}]$.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll test this out soon and post the results!

Comment: After setting up a few more test "dots" and hitting f5 about 100 times, the dots in the lower and upper regions did not move beyond the rounded borders! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are wellcome!

Answer (score 0):

If the top and bottom curve are circular arcs, given $y$ you can easily find the interval of $x$ values for which $(x,y)$ is inside your region.  Take $x$ to be a random number in that interval.